# Find the position of an attachment using MimeKit

Tags: c#, mime, mimekit

I have a MIME email message that I am parsing using MimeKit. I am able to load in the message and get all the attachment entities like so:

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = MimeMessage.Load(decodedDataStream);

int attachmentCount = 0;
foreach (MimeEntity attachment in mimeMessage.Attachments)
{
    attachmentCount++;

    string fileName = "-a" + attachmentCount;

    using (FileStream stream = File.Create(Path.Combine(message.Id + fileName)))
    {
            if (attachment is MessagePart)
            {
                    var part = (MessagePart)attachment;

                    part.Message.WriteTo(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                    var part = (MimePart)attachment;

                    part.Content.WriteTo(stream);
            }
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there any way to get the file offset / position of a particular attachment.

My requirement is to get the location of each attachment in the MIME file. Is there any way I can achieve this? I can see that LumiSoft has a feature to get the PositionSectionStart / PositionBodyStart.

[image: LumiSoft]

Does MimeKit have any way of doing this, or is there some other way to get the file offset for an attachment?

Comment: Mime is just data in the body of a Request/Response.  Each Mime attachment starts with two dashes on a new line.  You can use any tool to examine the body of the message.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

Comment: Yes, MimeKit does have a way of getting this information, but unfortunately it is not stored on the MimePart objects. You have to get that information from the MimeParser (or the ExperimentalMimeParser) via events (or overriding the virtual methods that provide that info). I can try to write up an example of how to use that (would probably be worth adding to the docs anyway) but which offsets do you want? The start/end of the MIME parts? or the start/end offsets of the *content* of those MIME parts?

Comment: In the meantime, you can check out MimeKit's unit tests for this feature here: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/UnitTests/MimeParserTests.cs#L2540

Answer (score 1):

```
class MimeOffsets
{
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    public long? MboxMarkerOffset { get; set; }

    public int LineNumber { get; set; }

    public long BeginOffset { get; set; }

    public long HeadersEndOffset { get; set; }

    public long EndOffset { get; set; }

    public MimeOffsets Message { get; set; }

    public List<MimeOffsets> Children { get; set; }

    public long Octets { get; set; }

    public int? Lines { get; set; }
}

public static void MimeOffsetsExample (string fileName)
{
    using (var stream = fileName.OpenRead (fileName)) {
        var messages = new Dictionary<MimeMessage, MimeOffsets> ();
        var entities = new Dictionary<MimeEntity, MimeOffsets> ();
        MimeOffsets messageOffsets = null;

        var parser = new MimeParser (stream, MimeFormat.Entity);

        // Connect a handler to track MimeMessage begin offsets
        parser.MimeMessageBegin += delegate (sender, args) {
            var parser = (MimeParser) sender;

            // Create a new MimeOffsets for this message.
            var offsets = new MimeOffsets {
                BeginOffset = args.BeginOffset,
                LineNumber = args.LineNumber
            };

            if (args.Parent != null) {
                // If we get here, then it means that the MimeMessage is part of
                // a message/rfc822 "attachment".
                var parentOffsets = entities[args.Parent];
                parentOffsets.Message = offsets;
            } else {
                // Otherwise, this is the top-level MimeMessage.
                offsets.MboxMarkerOffset = parser.MboxMarkerOffset;
                messageOffsets = offsets;
            }

            messages.Add (args.Message, offsets);
        };

        // Connect a handler to track MimeMessage end offsets
        parser.MimeMessageEnd += delegate (sender, args) {
            // Our MimeMessageBegin event handler already created a MimeOffsets for
            // this message. Use the `messages` dictionary to retrieve it.
            var offsets = messages[args.Message];

            // Track the size of the MimeMessage in octets (aka bytes), the offset
            // for the end of the header block, and the end of the message.
            offsets.Octets = args.EndOffset - args.HeadersEndOffset;
            offsets.HeadersEndOffset = args.HeadersEndOffset;
            offsets.EndOffset = args.EndOffset;
        };

        // Connect a handler to track MimeEntity begin offsets
        parser.MimeEntityBegin += delegate (sender, args) {
            // Create a new MimeOffsets for this MIME entity (which could be a MimePart, MessagePart, or Multipart).
            var offsets = new MimeOffsets {
                MimeType = args.Entity.ContentType.MimeType,
                BeginOffset = args.BeginOffset,
                LineNumber = args.LineNumber
            };

            if (args.Parent != null && entities.TryGetValue (args.Parent, out var parentOffsets)) {
                parentOffsets.Children ??= new List<MimeOffsets> ();
                parentOffsets.Children.Add (offsets);
            }

            entities.Add (args.Entity, offsets);
        };

        // Connect a handler to track MimeEntity end offsets
        parser.MimeEntityEnd += delegate (sender, args) {
            // Our MimeEntityBegin event handler already created a MimeOffsets for
            // this entity. Use the `entities` dictionary to retrieve it.
            var offsets = entities[args.Entity];

            // Track the size of the MimeEntity in octets (aka bytes), the offset
            // for the end of the header block, the end of the entity, and the
            // line count.
            offsets.Octets = args.EndOffset - args.HeadersEndOffset;
            offsets.HeadersEndOffset = args.HeadersEndOffset;
            offsets.EndOffset = args.EndOffset;
            offsets.Lines = args.Lines;
        };

        // Parse the message (which will emit the events as appropriate).
        var message = parser.ParseMessage ();

        // Now we can find out the offsets of each attachment:
        foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments) {
            var offsets = entities[attachment];

            Console.WriteLine ($"The offsets for the {bodyPart.ContentType} attachment are:");
            Console.WriteLine ($"  - LineNumber: {offsets.LineNumber}")
            Console.WriteLine ($"  - BeginOffset: {offsets.BeginOffset}");
            Console.WriteLine ($"  - HeadersEndOffset: {offsets.HeadersEndOffset}"); // Note: This is also where the *content* begins.
            Console.WriteLine ($"  - EndOffset: {offsets.BeginOffset}");
            Console.WriteLine ($"  - Octets: {offsets.Octets}");
            Console.WriteLine ($"  - Lines: {offsets.Lines}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you